# Google's BERT for NLP: replace foreign characters in vocab.txt to add words?

Tags: nlp

I am fine-tuning the BERT model but need to add a few thousand words. I know that one can replace the ~1000 `[unused#]` lines at the top of the vocab.txt, but I also notice there are thousands of single foreign characters (unicode) in the file, which I will never use. For fine-tuning, is it possible to replace those with my words, fine tune, and have model still work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The unused words weights are essentially randomly initialized only as they have not been used. If you just replace them with your own words but don't pretrain further on your domain specific corpus, then it would essentially remain random only. So, there won't be much benifit IMO, if you replace and continue with finetuning.

Let me point you to this [github issue](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/9). According to author of the paper:

> My recommendation would be to just use the existing wordpiece vocab
>   and run pre-trianing for more steps on the in-domain text, and it
>   should learn the compositionality "for free". Keep in mind that with a
>   wordpiece vocabulary there are basically no out-of-vocabulary words,
>   and you don't really know which words were seen in the pre-training
>   and not. Just because a word was split up by word pieces doesn't mean
>   it's rare, in fact many words which were split into wordpieces were
>   seen 5,000+ times in the pre-training data.
>
> But if you want to add more vocab you can either: (a) Just replace the
>   "[unusedX]" tokens with your vocabulary. Since these were not used
>   they are effectively randomly initialized. (b) Append it to the end of
>   the vocab, and write a script which generates a new checkpoint that is
>   identical to the pre-trained checkpoint, but but with a bigger vocab
>   where the new embeddings are randomly initialized (for initialized we
>   used tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02)). This will likely
>   require mucking around with some tf.concat() and tf.assign() calls.

Hope this helps!